# $\displaystyle\mathop {\lim }\limits_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{{x{y^2}z}}{{{x^2} + 4{y^4} + 9{z^6}}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Consider the following limit $\displaystyle\mathop {\lim
>  }\limits_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{{x{y^2}z}}{{{x^2} + 4{y^4} +
>  9{z^6}}}$. If the limit does exist, compute its value; if it doesn't,
>   give a proof.

I feel that the limit does exist, judging by the exponents of $z$. So as usual when it comes to showing the existence of a three-variable limit, I tried to convert to spherical coordinates. But that method can't seem to work in this case. So is there any way to evaluate its limit? Or the limit does not exist at all and I'd better try to disprove its existence?
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is close to Christian Blatter's answer, but I'll avoid the trig functions and spell out some more details.  For any $x,y,z$, define $M$ to be the maximum of $x^2$, $y^4$, and $z^6$.  Notice that $M>0$ for all $(x,y,z)\neq(0,0,0)$ and that $M\to0$ as $(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)$.

Consider the denominator $x^2+4y^4+9z^6$ of the fraction in the problem.  One of the three summands here is $M$, possibly multiplied by 4 or 9, and the other two summands are nonnegative.  So the whole denominator is $\geq M$.

Next consider the numerator, $xy^2z$.  By definition of $M$, we have $|x|\leq M^{1/2}$, $|y|\leq M^{1/4}$ (so $y^2\leq M^{1/2}$), and $z\leq M^{1/6}$.  Thus, the absolute value of the numerator is $\leq M^{7/6}$.

Combining the lower bound on the denominator and the upper bound on the absolute value of the numerator, we get that the whole fraction is bounded in absolute value by $M^{1/6}$.  Since $M$ approaches $0$ as $(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)$, so does the fraction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I wonder how the solution looks like if the exponents of $x,y$ and $z$ in the denominator are odd. And in general, given $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{{{x^a}{y^b}{z^c}}}{{k{x^p} + l{x^q} + m{x^r}}}$, what conditions should be imposed on $a,b,c,k,l,m,p,q,r$ to guarantee the limit's existence?

Answer (score 2):

From $(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)$ it follows that 
$$r^2:=x^2 +(2y^2)^2+ (3z^3)^2\to 0\ .\tag{1}$$
Looking at $(1)$ we can see that given $x$, $y$, $z$ there are $\phi$ and $\theta$ such that 
$$x=r\cos\phi\cos\theta,\quad 2y^2=r\sin\phi\cos\theta,\quad 3z^3=r\sin\theta\ .$$
It follows that
$$\left|{x y^2 z\over x^2+4y^2+9z^6}\right|\leq {C r^{7/3}\over r^2}=C r^{1\over 3}\to 0$$
for some $C>0$ when $(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)$.

Comment: A priori, it is not clear that $C$ is constant or even majorized by a constant.  The angles might vary with $r$ in complicated ways.

Comment: @Andreas Blass: The sines and cosines of these angles are bounded in absolute value by 1. I think that $C=1$ would be o.k.

Comment: Your bound is probably OK, in view of the fact that all the coefficients in the denominator are positive, so there's no danger of cancellation between these powers of sines and cosines.