# limit of a function of three variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I would like to ask you how to solve the limit at the origin of the following function:

$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^3y^3z^2}{x^6+y^8+z^{10}}$$

I am quite sure that it is $0$, but I cannot find a function majorizing $f$ and going to $0$ at the origin (in order to use the sandwich thm).

Thank you in advance for your help.

P.S.:I am looking for an alternative method than using spherical coordinates.

Comment: Maybe try a different coordinate system (spherical, cylindrical etc). Or look at different paths by setting $y = ax$, $z = bx$.

Comment: @Mattos: Have you tried any of your own suggestions?

Comment: For inspiration: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/317508/159845.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=x^3$, $Y=y^4$, $Z=z^{5}$. Then $r^2=X^2+Y^2+Z^2=x^6+y^8+z^{10}$ and
$$|x^3y^3z^2|=|X||Y|^{3/4}|Z|^{2/5}\leq r^{1+3/4+2/5}=r^{43/20}$$
where
$$X=r\cos\theta\cos\phi,\quad Y=r\cos\theta\sin\phi,\quad Z=r\sin\theta\ .$$

Therefore, as $(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)$, it follows that $r\to 0$ and
$$\left|{x^3y^3z^2\over x^6+y^8+z^{10}}\right|\leq {r^{43/20}\over r^2}=r^{3\over 20}\to 0.$$

Comment: @Dr. MV Yeah, it is hard to "think different"!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x'=x^3$, $y'=y^4$ and $z'=z^5$.  Then, we have

$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}\frac{x^3y^3z^2}{x^6+y^8+z^5}=\lim_{(x',y',z')\to (0,0,0)}\frac{x'y'^{3/4}z'^{2/5}}{x'^2+y'^2+z'^2}$$

Conversion to spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$ where $x'=r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$, $y'=r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$, and $z'=r\cos(\theta)$ reveals that

$$\lim_{(x',y',z')\to (0,0,0)}\frac{x'y'^{3/4}z'^{2/5}}{x'^2+y'^2+z'^2}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^{43/40}\sin^{7/4}(\theta)\cos^{2/5}(\theta)\cos(\phi)\sin^{4/3}(\phi)}{r^2}$$

which clearly approaches zero!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark